# Advanced MultiThreading in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new to android, I need to start a Thread Multiple times to do a regular work as the listen a thing. But I searched and found that can't do this. So I decided to put

```
while(true){
listen some thing
do another something depends for listen
}
```

in the `run()` method.

But How can I implements this idea? Is it possible ? and How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Handler.post()` whenever you want to do operations in the UI thread.

So let's say in the callback (which is running in separate thread) you want to change a TextView's text, you should use Handler.post(). In Android, as in many other UI frameworks, UI elements (widgets) can be only modified from main thread.

```
mHandler = new Handler();

new Thread(new Runnable(
  @Override
  public void run () {
    // Perform long-running task here
    // (like audio buffering).
    // you may want to update some progress
    // bar every second, so use handler:
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run () {
       // make operation on UI - on example
       // on progress bar.
     }
    });
  }
)).start();
```

Of course, if the task you want to perform is really long and there is a risk user might switch to some another app in the meantime, you should consider using `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your thread inside a while loop with `true` condition, it'll kill your device. You'r device will hang. Your code should be event triggered. You can have a `Service` running in the background to do that and listen for your events.

Comment: so How do I do this? for true condition i can put app is running!